# Facebook like button in flex app

Tags: html, apache-flex, facebook, iframe

This button is basically hosted on a html page and used trough an iframe.

I believe flex does not have iframes out of the box. Are there are any good iframe components i can use?

Comment: I'm trying to get a "like" button in Flash but I can't find anything about it

Comment: did the facebook like button work?

Comment: The custom iframe element is causing problems, i couldnt position it where i want. But i believe if you could it should work. I however gave up on it and used a share button instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no problem just see my sample app.
Here is running application code i upload at

http://hotfile.com/dl/107411236/c963b97/The_IFRAME.zip.html

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

> "The Flex-IFrame component allows
>   developers to embed an html page
>   inside a Flex application."

http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/